# Como agrupar por varias columnas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Buen dia , podrian ayudarme con...

Tengo el Siguiente DataFrame

```
     fecha       Medicamento     Dosis   ClaseServicio
0   2022-11-10  Vancomicina IV  4000.00 HOSPITALIZACION
1   2022-11-12  Vancomicina IV  2.00    HOSPITALIZACION
2   2022-11-01  Ceftriaxona IV  10.00   HOSPITALIZACION
3   2022-11-10  Ceftriaxona IV  10.00   HOSPITALIZACION
4   2022-11-10  Ertapenem IV    20.00   HOSPITALIZACION
5   2022-11-10  Ertapenem IV    20.00   HOSPITALIZACION
6   2022-11-10  Cefepime IV 9.00    CUIDADO CRITICO
7   2022-11-10  Cefepime IV 9.00    CUIDADO CRITICO
8   2022-11-10  Meropenem IV    30.00   HOSPITALIZACION
9   2022-11-10  Meropenem IV    15.00   CUIDADO CRITICO
10  2022-11-10  Piperacilna/tazobactam IVIV 3.00    CUIDADO CRITICO
```

Primero deberia , Separar las filas por tipo de valor  Columna "ClaseServicio" , los cuales son "HOSPITALIZACION" o "CUIDADO CRITICO",
Segundo deberia , deberia sumar la Dosis Columna "Dosis" de cada tipo de Medicamento de Columna "Medicamento"

Todo esto para tener la siguiente salida.
Entiendo que puede se innecesarios algun paso
Ejemplo:

[image: SAlida DataFRame DEseado]

Esto por Cada Mes que se tiene.

lo he intentado de la siguiente forma:

**funcion CrossTab**
 `pd.crosstab(df_filtro.PAV ,[ df_filtro.ClaseServicio], aggfunc = "sum", values = df_filtro.Dosis)`

`pd.crosstab([df_filtro.fecha,df_filtro.PAV ],[ df_filtro.ClaseServicio], aggfunc = "sum", values = df_filtro.Dosis)`

PEro no se como resolver lo ultimo que me muestre por mes la sumatoria de cada PAV/Medicamento.

Agradeceria su ayuda. Saludos

Comment: Buen día, no es muy claro lo que deseas hacer, el `dataframe` que pusiste al inicio no se ve reflejado en la imagen que pones. Crea un ejemplo completo para poder entender lo que deseas hacer.

Comment: Tienes Razon ya lo edite mucho mejor , espero se comprenda bien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Puedes lograrlo al utilizar [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) junto con [`pandas.DataFrame.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html)

Utilizando el siguiente `dataframe` desde el archivo "sample2.csv" como ejemplo:

```
        fecha                  Medicamento   Dosis    ClaseServicio
0  2022-11-10               Vancomicina IV  4000.0  HOSPITALIZACION
1  2022-11-12               Vancomicina IV     2.0  HOSPITALIZACION
2  2022-11-01               Ceftriaxona IV    10.0  HOSPITALIZACION
3  2022-11-10               Ceftriaxona IV    10.0  HOSPITALIZACION
4  2022-11-10                 Ertapenem IV    20.0  HOSPITALIZACION
5  2022-11-10                 Ertapenem IV    20.0  HOSPITALIZACION
6  2022-11-10                  Cefepime IV     9.0  CUIDADO CRITICO
7  2022-11-10                  Cefepime IV     9.0  CUIDADO CRITICO
8  2022-11-10                 Meropenem IV    30.0  HOSPITALIZACION
9  2022-11-10                 Meropenem IV    15.0  CUIDADO CRITICO
10 2022-11-10  Piperacilna/tazobactam IVIV     3.0  CUIDADO CRITICO
11 2022-12-10               Vancomicina IV  4000.0  HOSPITALIZACION
12 2022-12-12               Vancomicina IV     2.0  HOSPITALIZACION
13 2022-12-01               Ceftriaxona IV    10.0  HOSPITALIZACION
14 2022-12-10               Ceftriaxona IV    10.0  HOSPITALIZACION
15 2022-12-10                 Ertapenem IV    20.0  HOSPITALIZACION
16 2022-12-10                 Ertapenem IV    20.0  HOSPITALIZACION
17 2022-12-10                  Cefepime IV     9.0  CUIDADO CRITICO
18 2022-12-10                  Cefepime IV     9.0  CUIDADO CRITICO
19 2022-12-10                 Meropenem IV    30.0  HOSPITALIZACION
20 2022-12-10                 Meropenem IV    15.0  CUIDADO CRITICO
21 2022-12-10  Piperacilna/tazobactam IVIV     3.0  CUIDADO CRITICO
```

**Nota:** Agregué los mismos datos pero para diciembre para que el resultado se pueda ver de forma correcta.

Hay que agrupar el `dataframe` por tipo de "Medicamento", luego por mes y por "ClaseServicio". Pero como te interesa mostrar el nombre del mes utilizamos [`pandas.Series.dt.month_name`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.month_name.html) con locale `es` para mostrar los nombres en español.

**Nota:** Como requisito previo, la columna "fecha" debe ser de tipo `datetime64[ns]`.

```
df.groupby(['Medicamento', df['fecha'].dt.month_name(locale='es'), 'ClaseServicio'])
```

Ya que se agrupó el `dataframe` necesitas la suma de "Dosis", por lo que la línea anterior quedaría así:

```
df.groupby(['Medicamento', df['fecha'].dt.month_name(locale='es'), 'ClaseServicio'])['Dosis'].sum()
```

Que devolvería el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
Medicamento                  fecha      ClaseServicio  
Cefepime IV                  Diciembre  CUIDADO CRITICO      18.0
                             Noviembre  CUIDADO CRITICO      18.0
Ceftriaxona IV               Diciembre  HOSPITALIZACION      20.0
                             Noviembre  HOSPITALIZACION      20.0
Ertapenem IV                 Diciembre  HOSPITALIZACION      40.0
                             Noviembre  HOSPITALIZACION      40.0
Meropenem IV                 Diciembre  CUIDADO CRITICO      15.0
                                        HOSPITALIZACION      30.0
                             Noviembre  CUIDADO CRITICO      15.0
                                        HOSPITALIZACION      30.0
Piperacilna/tazobactam IVIV  Diciembre  CUIDADO CRITICO       3.0
                             Noviembre  CUIDADO CRITICO       3.0
Vancomicina IV               Diciembre  HOSPITALIZACION    4002.0
                             Noviembre  HOSPITALIZACION    4002.0
```

**Nota:** Tanto los índices como las columnas van de 0 a `n`, por lo que la columna "Medicamento" tendría el índice 0, "fecha" el índice 1 y "ClaseServicio el índice 2.

Utilizamos `unstack(1)` para que el grupo de los meses se convierta en columnas, ahora el multi índice quedaría con 2 elementos que serían "Medicamento" y "ClaseServicio", utilizamos nuevamente `unstack(1) para que el grupo de "ClaseServicio" (Que ahora tiene índice 1) se convierta en un segundo "grupo" de columnas.

Ejemplo completo:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample2.csv', parse_dates=['fecha'])
print(df.groupby(['Medicamento', df['fecha'].dt.month_name(locale='es'), 'ClaseServicio'])['Dosis'].sum().unstack(1).unstack(1, fill_value=0))
```

Esto imprime el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
fecha                             Diciembre                       Noviembre  
ClaseServicio               CUIDADO CRITICO HOSPITALIZACION CUIDADO CRITICO HOSPITALIZACION  
Medicamento                                                                   
Cefepime IV                            18.0             0.0            18.0             0.0
Ceftriaxona IV                          0.0            20.0             0.0            20.0
Ertapenem IV                            0.0            40.0             0.0            40.0
Meropenem IV                           15.0            30.0            15.0            30.0
Piperacilna/tazobactam IVIV             3.0             0.0             3.0             0.0
Vancomicina IV                          0.0          4002.0             0.0          4002.0
```

Comment: esta increiblemente explicado tan sencillamente , aun no manejo o se utilizar bien el metodo , unstack().
Muchas gracias.

Si esto se quisiera imprimir en un excel , quedaria el mismo orden ??

Comment: @JaderAlvarinoGarzon, Cambiar el orden de las columnas te queda de "tarea" ;)  Si la respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. Lectura recomendada [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).